# What's a dead ogonek, and where is it on my keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I was changing a shortcut on gnome terminal and I found that:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HBnzuuJ.png]

What is it?

Answer (score 13):

An [ogonek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogonek) is an diacritic mark that looks like a right-facing hook placed underneath a letter. It originates from central European languages such as Polish and Lithuanian.

ĄĘĮǪŲY̨ ąęį ǫųy̨

A [dead key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) is a key that doesn't insert any character when you press it, but affects the next character you type. Dead keys add an accent to the next letter. So if you press <kbd>dead ˛</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd>, you get the character `Ą`.

It's weird to have a shortcut on this key. Unless your keyboard layout is meant for a language that uses this accent, you wouldn't have this key.

Comment: Actually, many Ubuntu keyboard layouts have the dead ogonek on AltGr+Shift+[key left of backspace]. That is based on an ISO layer and not necessarily found on other OSes. Also, keyboard layouts for languages that have this diacritic would have the letters rather than the daed key – at least, that is the case for Lithuanian. On the other case, Hungarian (which does not use the ogonek diacritic) has the dead ogonek, as do some other Central European layouts.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard about this "dead ogonek", but I googled something for you, which may probably be helpful:

Here you can find the explaination of a keyboard dead-key: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key

And here what does "ogonek" mean: http://www.personal.psu.edu/ejp10/blogs/gotunicode/2009/01/ogonek-vs-cedilla-accent.html

Answer (score 1):

There are so called "dead" keys which do not produce a character when typing but are used to put diacritics such as accents on characters.

One of these diacritics is the [Ogonek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogonek), or "Nasal Hook", below shown for the letter O:

## Ǫ